# SQL query solution confusion, confused by group by and having clause

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, having

So basically this is the database:
Consider the relation schema of the COMPANY database given below

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

and the question is:

Give the last name and SSN of those managers who work on two or more projects located in Cleveland.

The correction solution is like this:

```
select Lname
  from Employee e, Department d
where (e.ssn = d.mgrssn) 
   and  ssn in (
                      select  w.essn
                       from   works_on w, Project p
                      where w.pno = p.pnumber
                          and  p.plocation = 'Cleveland'
                      group by w.essn
                      having count(*) >= 2
                     )
```

My question is:

1. Why is the works_on added?
2. employee e and department d, why are they both needed? I  thought we are only finding employee
3. finally, the most confusing part is group by w.essn having count(*) >= 2,
   should the >=2 part be used for project p instead? since we are finding out
   the project number that are greater than 2?

If you guys have time, can you please put signs by the right solution to show
which part belong to which employee and why are they needed. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry is too broad, We will have to teach you a course of db to cover all those points. You should ask your teacher. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try. Hope this helps.
Your question is:

*2.employee e and department d, why are they both needed? I thought we are only finding employee*

**No, the requirement is not for finding employee, it is for finding Managers**

*1.Why is the works_on added?*

**Without the works_on, how do you know **which employee worked on which project**?**

*3.finally, the most confusing part is group by w.essn having count(*) >= 2, should the >=2 part be used for project p instead? since we are finding out the project number that are greater than 2?*

**Are you looking for projects that involve 2 or more employees or are you looking for employees who have worked on 2 or more projects?**

Comment: Thank, can you please write the comments around the solution and I will accept it. like just some brief descriptions around parts of the solution. sorry because I get confused a lot when I try to read code.